# Docker doesn't create database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I have Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER root
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD root
ENV POSTGRES_DB world
COPY world.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

I run `docker build -t postgres`, then I create container but it doesn't create database in PG. Does anyone have any idea?

world.sql :

```
CREATE TABLE city (
                      id integer NOT NULL,
                      name text NOT NULL,
                      countrycode character(3) NOT NULL,
                      district text NOT NULL,
                      population integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE country (
                         code character(3) NOT NULL,
                         name text NOT NULL,
                         continent text NOT NULL,
                         region text NOT NULL,
                         surfacearea real NOT NULL,
                         indepyear smallint,
                         population integer NOT NULL,
                         lifeexpectancy real,
                         gnp numeric(10,2),
                         gnpold numeric(10,2),
                         localname text NOT NULL,
                         governmentform text NOT NULL,
                         headofstate text,
                         capital integer,
                         code2 character(2) NOT NULL,
                         CONSTRAINT country_continent_check CHECK ((((((((continent = 'Asia'::text) OR (continent = 'Europe'::text)) OR (continent = 'North America'::text)) OR (continent = 'Africa'::text)) OR (continent = 'Oceania'::text)) OR (continent = 'Antarctica'::text)) OR (continent = 'South America'::text)))
);

CREATE TABLE countrylanguage (
                                 countrycode character(3) NOT NULL,
                                 "language" text NOT NULL,
                                 isofficial boolean NOT NULL,
                                 percentage real NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen because it says so in the guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide container logs?

I ran your solution but it works in my case

The database has been successfully created

```
docker run -d --name my-postgresdb-container -p 5432:5432 postgres
docker logs <CONTAINER ID>
```

Comment: Cant edit my post and provide full logs
But in logs i have the following:
    `server started

    CREATE DATABASE



    /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/world.sql

    CREATE TABLE

    CREATE TABLE

    CREATE TABLE`

Comment: @Alex I have the same log output. Why did you decide that the database was not created? I am now connected to it via pgAdmin and see your tables...

Comment: Did you get the world database? @KubePony

Comment: @Alex yes, now I'm connected to it. Can you explain how you determined that the database is not being created? It is, but inside a container because your solution doesn't use docker volumes

Comment: i don't see the world db in pgAdmin @KubyPony

Comment: @Alex did you manage to connect to the database through pgAdmin? Also, If possible, I would double-check the logs for errors. You can run `docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> ls /var/lib/postgresql/data/base`, in my case i see 4 directories

Comment: Now I have connected to my world database in cmd and in psql I can see this database but when I try to connect to it in pgAdmin I get an error that no such database exists. @KubePony

Comment: maybe it's different versions issue...

Comment: I also see 4 directories) I don't know, i use pgAdmin 14, psql 14... @KubePony

Comment: Now i have the world db, when i connected to psql from docker exec -it postgres bash, but when i try to get \l from main cmd: psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -W  i don't see the world db. Any ideas? @KubePony

Comment: Omg... I don't know why but I opened a process on port 5432 and I don't know how it worked when I created new containers on that port. But I killed the process on the port and everything works. Thanks for your help! @KubePony

Answer (score 0):

Syntax issue

```
ENV POSTGRES_USER=root
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
ENV POSTGRES_DB=world
```

Comment: Changed, but doesn't help